# find element in node html

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I don't know what I am doing wrong in my code I want to loop all p tag and find image and wrap each with figure tag

Here is my html example :

```
$html = <<<EOF
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx1" />
    <span class="sourceimgtest">AAAAA</span>
</p>

<p>
    <img src="xxxxx2">
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx3">
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx4">
    <span class="sourceimgtest">BBBBB</span>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx5">
    <span class="sourceimgtest">CCCCC</span>
</p>
<p>
    <img src="xxxxx6">
    <span class="sourceimgtest">DDDDD</span>

    <img src="xxxxx7">
    <span class="sourceimgtest">EEEEE</span>

    <img src="xxxxx8">
    <span class="sourceimgtest">FFFFF</span>

</p>
EOF;
```

And the expected output :

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <figure>
    <img src="xxxxx1" />
    </figure>
    <span class="sourceimgtest">AAAAA</span>
</p>

<p>
    <figure>
    <img src="xxxxx2">
    </figure>
</p>
<p>
    <figure>
    <img src="xxxxx3">
    </figure>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <figure>
    <img src="xxxxx4">
    </figure>
    <span class="sourceimgtest">BBBBB</span>
</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
</p>
<p>
    <figure>
    <img src="xxxxx5">
    </figure>
    <span class="sourceimgtest">CCCCC</span>
</p>
<p>
    <figure>
    <img src="xxxxx6">
    </figure>
    <span class="sourceimgtest">DDDDD</span>

    <figure>
    <img src="xxxxx7">
    </figure>
    <span class="sourceimgtest">EEEEE</span>

    <figure>
    <img src="xxxxx8">
    </figure>
    <span class="sourceimgtest">FFFFF</span>

</p>
```

And this is the php I am using :

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


$matches = $xpath->query('//p');


if($matches->length > 0 ){


    foreach($matches as $node){

    $node_img_match = $node->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if(isset($node_img_match)){
        foreach($node_img_match as $node_img ){

            $figure_node = $dom->createElement('figure');
            $figure_node->appendChild($node_img);  
            $node->parentNode->replaceChild($figure_node, $node);

        }
    }
}

$contenu = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $contenu;
```

And when I execute it I have this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function replaceChild() on null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see `$node` is your `<p>` tag, no need get a parent of this tag. You should replace exactly in `$node`. But also you should get a copy of `<img>` tag to replace it by with `$node_img->cloneNode()`

Try this one

```
foreach ($node_img_match as $node_img) {
   $figure_node = $dom->createElement('figure');
   $figure_node->appendChild($node_img->cloneNode());
   $node->replaceChild($figure_node,$node_img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `$node` in this line:

```
$node->parentNode->replaceChild($figure_node, $node);
```

if I'm not mistaken is referring to the `<p>` element and so `parentNode` would refer to a `null` element based on your HTML.

This is just a wild guess, but you can probably put it like this:

```
$node->replaceChild($figure_node, $node_img_match);
```

or

```
$node_img_match->parentNode->replaceChild($figure_node, $node_img_match);
```

Comment: I have the same error with this code
$node->replaceChild($figure_node, $node_img_match);
And this error 
 Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$parentNod
with this code 
$node_img_match->parentNode->replaceChild($figure_node, $node_img_match);